# Application Status script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have a start and stop script in-place and need a script that gives status on Linux server. My start script looks as below, can you please let me know if I can add some arguments/command to get my application status.

```
#!/bin/ksh

java_home=`cat /apps/abc.properties | grep "$1|" | cut "-d|" -f2`
service_executable=`cat /apps/abc.properties | grep "$1|" | cut "-d|" -f3`
service_home=`cat /apps/abc.properties | grep "$1|" | cut "-d|" -f4`
service_opts=`cat /apps/abc.properties | grep "$1|" | cut "-d|" -f5`

export JAVA_HOME=$java_home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
echo start $service_home
cd $service_home/bin
nohup $service_executable start $service_opts
```

abc.properties has below values

```
abc-3.7.3|/apps/java/jdk1.8.0_66|rmc|/apps/rmc/abc-3.7.3|-M-Drmc.mmc.bind.port=8770
abc-3.7.3-spii|/apps/java/jdk1.8.0_66|rmc|/apps/rmc/abc-3.7.3-spii|-M-Drmc.mmc.bind.port=8770
```

I want a scrpit that can check each version of application(JVM) using port numbers and give me status for example abc-3.7.3"running"/ abc-3.7.3-spii"down".

Comment: You are missing $() around the commands.  For example: $(cat /apps/abc.properties | grep "$1|" | cut "-d|" -f2).  Also, the first line should start with #!.

Comment: @Mike, FYI -- your edit was adding eight-space indents; it should be exactly four.

Comment: @codeforester, eh? The OP has backticks; they don't need `$()`.

Comment: Charles, the back ticks weren't visible to me.  I do see them now.

Comment: @Raj1112, FYI, consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything that finds before asking questions here.

Comment: @Raj1112, ...frankly, init scripts are awful, and you shouldn't be using them at all. The right way to control a service is with a proper supervision system -- runit, DJB daemontools, systemd, upstart, supervisord, etc; all these will provide both startup/shutdown and status control for you, and support for automatically restarting your service in the event that it fails.

Comment: Look at your operating system's documentation -- current RHEL and CentOS ship with systemd, for instance; slightly older Ubuntu uses upstart; MacOS uses launchd; etc -- find out which process supervision system your operating system supports, and use it. Don't try to invent your own wheel on this one.

Comment: @ Charles .. currently my start and stop scripts are running without any issues and was thinking i can tweak this script to give status of application..like "running" or "not running" ..

Comment: @ Charles .. thanks for editing my post .. this is my first time to post of stackoverflow.. I will shellcheck.net from next time.. Thanks you..

Comment: I suggest that you specify exactly what you are looking for on your answer, including an example of the output you are looking for.

Comment: @JamilSaid Thanks I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick version would be to have a script that would extract the application name and the port number form the input file (ex. read APP + stuff + PORT) and then check if the port is opened (ex. in the netstat output grep for the port number).
This is a very short form that does just that:

```
while IFS="|=" read App _ _ _ _ Port; do
    netstat -lnt | grep -qw ":$Port" && echo "$App : running" || echo "$App : down"
done < abc.properties
```

Is it good enough?

Comment: In general, this looks pretty good! A few notes -- the conventional variable name to use for a placeholder is `_`, and your non-placeholder variables should actually have names with at least one lower-case character to avoid conflicting with a namespace [reserved by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) for environment variables with meaning to the shell or operating system.

Comment: (Yes, `read` is creating regular shell variables as opposed to environment variables, but setting a shell variable overwrites any preexisting like-named environment variable, meaning that the namespace is shared).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for pointing it out, now it's POSIX compliant :P

Comment: LGTM. (If I wanted to be *really* pedantic, I could point out that `condition && true-branch || false-branch` isn't the same as `if condition; then true-branch; else false-branch; fi` -- in the former, if `true-branch` fails for whatever reason, then `false-branch` will run even if `condition` succeeded -- but for the case of `echo`, it's unlikely that one would fail and the other after it succeed).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I agree. I think it's clear I use echo + conditional execution relying on the fact that "echo" never fails thus saving some lines in a quick script. Somehow I don't see these kind of code as part of an application, just a small handy toll which might be allowed to slip.

Comment: "Never fails" isn't quite strictly true -- run `exec >&-` and all subsequent writes to stdout in the same shell will fail, with a nonzero exit status in the case of `echo`; similar cases if redirected to disk and an out-of-space condition happens, to a network socket that closes, etc -- but indeed, one failing and the next succeeding is very, very unlikely, and you're right that it's a reasonable assumption to make in this case. To be entirely clear, I'm +1 on the answer, and have been since the edits that followed my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I tried using " if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; "and it worked fine on RHEL6 (4.82) but on RHEL5 I'm seeing a error below

lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: C
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: P
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: :
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: L
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: I
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: S
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: T
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: E
lsof: unsupported TCP/TPI info selection: N
lsof 4.78